# Stack gifs with FFmpeg without loss of quality

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I have two animated gifs of the same duration and size that I am trying to stack vertically with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg input_1.gif -i input_2.gif -filter_complex vstack -q:v 1 output.gif
```

The problem is that resulting gif experience quite some loss of quality. Furthermore, it seems that option `-q:v` has no effect at all, regardless of supplied value and (valid) positioning within command.

Does anybody know a way to overcome it?

Comment: See [How do I convert a video to GIF using ffmpeg, with reasonable quality?](https://superuser.com/a/556031/110524)

Comment: @llogan, I don't see a way to apply it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [vstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack), [split](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#split_002c-asplit), [palettegen](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#palettegen), and [paletteuse](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#paletteuse) filters:

```
ffmpeg input_1.gif -i input_2.gif -filter_complex "[0][1]vstack=inputs=2,split[y][z];[y]palettegen[pal];[z][pal]paletteuse" output.gif
```

Comment: I end up using slightly modified version of the answer with "[y]palettegen=stats_mode=single[pal];[z][pal]paletteuse=new=1". At cost of some additional memory, it generates and supply separate palette for each frame, rather than one for all; reducing the gap between the number of colors to encode and capacity of palette (256) = lesser drop in quality.